# Cisco AIR1042 AP does not recognize "configure" command

Tags: cisco, access-point

I try to configure a Cisco Aironet 1042N Series Access Point for Office Use. Web-browser interface is disabled by default. I must enable it for configuring but when I try to configure it from CLI I get this error.

```
APc471.fe8f.f47d#configure terminal
                  ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

Also I don't have any WLC device in my network I just want to use it for Office Network Extend but it gives this error frequently.

```
*Mar  1 00:38:57.175: %CAPWAP-3-DHCP_RENEW: Could not discover WLC using DHCP IP
. Renewing DHCP IP.
Not in Bound state.
*Mar  1 00:39:05.183: %CAPWAP-3-ERRORLOG: Invalid event 38 & state 2 combination
.
*Mar  1 00:39:05.305: %DHCP-6-ADDRESS_ASSIGN: Interface GigabitEthernet0 assigne
d DHCP address 10.1.1.67, mask 255.255.255.0, hostname APc471.fe8f.f47d

Translating "CISCO-CAPWAP-CONTROLLER.xxx.xxx"...domain server (10.1.1.3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the AP is currently configured as "Lightwieght"

This means it must work with a Wireless controller to function correctly, see the below link for the procedure to convert it back to autonomous:
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/customer/docs/wireless/access_point/conversion/lwapp/upgrade/guide/lwapnote.html#wp161272

Comment: thank you for the answer. When I talked to cisco support they told me this. And they will send me autonomous rom files.